# how to GROUP_CONCAT with Concat

Tags: mysql

```
Product name    supplier
A               Su1
A               Su1
A               Su2
B               Su1
C               Su3
```

I want like this

```
A - su1, A-su2, B-su1, C-su3
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
vtiger_salesorder.salesorder_no,

(Select 
group_concat(DISTINCT concat(vtiger_products.productname, '-', vtiger_vendor.vendorname ) SEPARATOR ', ') 
FROM
  vtiger_salesorder
LEFT Join vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
inner Join vtiger_products ON vtiger_products.productid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.productid
inner Join softMax_SalesOrderVendorInfo ON softMax_SalesOrderVendorInfo.salesorderid = vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid 
LEFT JOIN vtiger_vendor ON softMax_SalesOrderVendorInfo.vendorid = vtiger_vendor.vendorid
where (vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id 
AND vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid 
and  (softMax_SalesOrderVendorInfo.status = '0') )Group by vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid Limit 0,1) As SuName1

FROM
vtiger_salesorder
INNER JOIN vtiger_inventoryproductrel ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_inventoryproductrel.id
Inner Join vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_salesorder.salesorderid = vtiger_crmentity.crmid
Order by vtiger_salesorder.salesorder_no
```

Comment: You have not actually posted a question. What are you trying to do? How far have you got so far? What is the data that you are using? What is the *specific* problem that you have? How is the query that you posted related to the rest of the post?

Answer (score 0):

Given your original data, you can simply do this with something like:

```
select distinct group_concat(ProductName, '-', Supplier separator ', ')
from table t;
```

I have no idea what the query has to do with the question, because you already seem to have the data in the appropriate format.